# How can i show set of literals are satisfiable?

Tags: computer-science, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I know that,

> For any atom A, the literals A, ¬A are said to be complementary to
>   each other.
>
> A set of literals is satisfiable iff it does not contain complementary
>   pairs.
>
> A set Γ of formulas entails a formula F (symbolically, Γ |= F), if
>   every interpretation that satisfies all formulas in Γ satisfies F
>   also.
>
> Note that the notation for entailment uses the same symbol as the
>   notation for satisfaction introduced earlier, the difference being
>   that the expression on the left is an interpretation (I) in one case
>   and a set of formulas (Γ) in the other.
>
> The formulas entailed by Γ are also called the logical consequences
>   of Γ.

Let Γ be a set of literals. How can i show the, Γ is satisfiable iff there is no atom
A for which both A and ¬A belong to Γ.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to immediately follows from the first two definitions:

Def.1: For any atom A, the literals A, ¬A are said to be complementary to each other.

Def. 2 A set of literals is satisfiable iff it does not contain complementary pairs.

Therefore, a set of literals is satisfiable iff it does not contain literals A and ¬A for some atom A.

I suppose one could argue that definition 1 is not exactly clear on what the necessary conditions are for two literals to be complimentary. That is: it says that A and ¬A are complimentary, but it does not say that there cannot be two other kinds of literals (e.g. P and ¬Q) that are complimentary.  But, I can tell you that there are no such other pairs. So, to be clear, Definition 1 should really be:

Def.1': Two literals are complimentary iff they are of the form A and ¬A for some atom A

And now your conclusion is really just substituting Def. 1' into Def.2

Comment: I am kind of confused. Can you explain it a little bit more detail?